# Regular expression to check if a string contains certain value in a range of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need verify if string contains `+` in a interval of `single quotes`.

Example: `string str = "'Name + R405'"`.

But, it may happen that this string has more than one range with these values.

Example: `string str = "'Name + R405' + '(Name)'"`. In this case, the second `+` has a particular function in my code (it is out of single quotes).

In other words, I need identify only `+` that are within the single quotes. If have a other way for this, please explain for me.

**Update:**

Within single quotes (where is the text I need) may contain other single quotes. Therefore, I can not simply do checks to observe the beginning and end of a pair of single quotes.

**Update 2:**

I have a problem that might be a little complicated. My system has functions that take certain strings, and those strings are manipulated according to certain parameter:

> Text in single quotes are not altered / manipulated;
>
> To separate one text from another, is used +;
>
> My string must accept any character (this is a problem, I know).

For example: `"'Name' + On + 'Sector'"`. Strings like this, only have the part `"On"` manipulated by these methods. However, I have strings like `"'Name + Code' + On + 'Sector'"` or `"'Name'+Code '+ On +'Sector'"`. The `"Name + Code"`/`"Name'+Code"` will not be manipulated. Thus, the methods are "confused" with this kind of text and using the `+` and `single quotes` that are within parts of the text should that not be changed. But I can not change the methods, must perform a treatment in the string before calling the methods for them.

Comment: Then how do you differentiate between a single quote within a single quote and the start/end of a quoted string?  Or do you want all + that are not in a pattern like `' + '`?

Comment: Please supply an example string and what you expect the result to be.  As I understand the question, the regex I supplied works.

Comment: Are the other single quotes delimited and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iterating through the characters and keeping track of the single quotes you have seen.

```
public static bool HasPlusBetweenSingleQuotes(string str)
{
    bool inSingleQuotes = false;
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (c == '\'')
        {
            inSingleQuotes = !inSingleQuotes;
        }
        else if (c == '+' && inSingleQuotes)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you need the indexes of the plus signs within single quotes you can do the following.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> PlusBetweenSingleQuotesIndexes(string str)
{
    bool inSingleQuotes = false;
    for(int i=0;i<str.Length;i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '\'')
        {
            inSingleQuotes = !inSingleQuotes;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '+' && inSingleQuotes)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that these methods do not verify that every opening single quote has a closing single quote.

**EDIT**

If you have delimited quotes you just check if the previous character is the delimiter like `\`.

```
public static bool HasPlusBetweenSingleQuotes(string str)
{
    bool inSingleQuotes = false;
    char previous = ' '; // just defaulting to a space.
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (c == '\'' && previous != '\\')
        {
            inSingleQuotes = !inSingleQuotes;
        }
        else if (c == '+' && inSingleQuotes)
        {
            return true;
        }

        previous = c;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done with a regular expression (It might be possible?). It would be easier just to do this with a loop of characters and track if you are in or outside of quotes.

```
bool inBlock = false;    

foreach(var aChar in string mySentence) {
    //Testing with ascii codes &#43; == +, &#39; == '
    inBlock = (aChar == "&#39;") ? !inBlock : inBlock;
    if(inBlock && aChar == "&#43;")
         // do stuff here
}
```

As a note, the code might not work, I didn't test it.

Comment: You cannot compare `char` with `string`.  Instead just use `aChar == '\''` and `aChar == '+'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not invert the logic here and use the "concatenation sequences" as the structure for the pattern? These can be described as a sequence of **+** or **+On+** (with optional spaces) that are *in between* single quoted (possibly non-balanced) strings. Match the "glue" sequence bookended by a lookbehind for a `'` and a lookahead for a `'`, and you can parse the string into "single quoted strings" and "glue" tokens:

```
 var strings = new string[]
            {"'Name'+Code '+ On +'Sector'", 
             "'Name + R405' + '(Name)'",
             "'Name + Code' + On + 'Sector'",
             "'Name''+'Sector'"
            };

            const string pattern = @"(?<=')(\s*\+\s*|\s*\+\s*On\s*\+\s*)(?=')";

            foreach (string s in strings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("input:"+s);
                string[] tokens = Regex.Split(s, pattern);
                foreach (string token in tokens)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("token:->{0}<-", token);
                }                    
                //tokens.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)  //single quoted strings
                //tokens.Where((x, i) => i % 2 != 0) //glue sequences
            }
```